# Kendo UI and MSCRM Online version 9.0.x not comaptible?

Tags: kendo-ui, dynamics-crm

Anyone know if Kendo UI has known problems working in MSCRM Online version 9.0.2? Any word from Telerik about a fix/update?  Thanks!!

Our custom MSCRM solution is working fine with MSCRM Online version 8.2.x, but not working with version 9.0.x.  Testing appears to indicate problems with loss of Global context items and likely related to ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx.

I noticed a post about what sounds similar (link below).

[Web Resource in Dynamics 365—Kendo UI destroyed by jQuery loaded by ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158725/web-resource-in-dynamics-365-kendo-ui-destroyed-by-jquery-loaded-by-clientglobal)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as its not clear what you are asking. It feels like you could probably debug this further and update your question, e.g. are you seeing some specific error? Kendo and CRM aren't specifically compatible or not compatible as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask my question is: Is anyone else encountering problems with their existing use of Kendo UI following move up to v9.x of MSCRM?

Comment: then that's not really the sort of question that is suitable for this site. This is a Q&A site to solve specific problems, not a general discussion forum. For example; a better question (for this site) would be something along the lines of "I'm using Kendo UI within CRM online to do [something], here is my [code], but I'm getting this [error]". https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Are you using your own jQuery file or the version included in CRM? I have had some problems with the files CRM includes on its pages

Answer (score 0):

CRM 9.0.x introduces (and recommends) new ways of retrieving the `FormContext`. A lot of the old methods including `Xrm.Page` are being deprecated.

Here's the list of deprecated methods on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated)

Instead of `Xrm.Page` you have to pass the execution context in when you configure your form scripts: Here's the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/clientapi-execution-context)

There is a JavaScript analyser in the XRM Toolbox that can be used to identify scripts that contain deprecated code