# Kendo UI Issue with latest MSCRM Online version 9.0.2.x

Tags: kendo-ui, dynamics-crm

In this post:
[Web Resource in Dynamics 365—Kendo UI destroyed by jQuery loaded by ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158725/web-resource-in-dynamics-365-kendo-ui-destroyed-by-jquery-loaded-by-clientglobal)

it is stated:

> In version 9.0.2.54 of Dynamics 365 online, I found that the newer version of ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx loads its own version of jQuery without checking to see if one is already present.

How can I determine if the newer version of `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` loads its own version of jQuery without checking to see if one is already present?

I believe I may have same issue as in the linked question, but I'm unsure how I could diagnose that I'm in fact facing the same problems.

Comment: Are you including ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx inside the iframe where you use Kendo UI?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a simple way to do that would;

- Debugging the page (e.g. F12) and seeing which jQuery files are loaded.
- If you know which version of jQuery you expect to be loaded, then you can compare that to which version is actually loaded by calling `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery)` in your code.

```js
alert(jQuery.fn.jquery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```